# java.util.vector cannot be cast to javax.collections.observablelist

Tags: java, tableview, javafx, observable

I`m getting this error:

> java.util.vector cannot be cast to javax.collections.observablelist

When trying to populate TableView with List

this is my code error occurs on last line

```
try {
   emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("shopPu");
   em = emf.createEntityManager();
   List<Products> proList = em.createQuery("select p from Products p").getResultList();
   tableView.setItems((ObservableList<Products>)proList);
} catch (Exception e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

How i can bind List to my table or what is correct way to convert List to ObservableList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FXCollections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) to create an `ObservableList`.

```
ObservableList<E> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
```

Comment: Thank i set items but my dataTable does not showing data. Debugger shows that observableList contains 3 rows. Do i need any command to display after setItems?

Comment: @user525717 You should probably ask another question with the relevant code to your problem.

Comment: please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259748/javafx-2-x-tableview-binding-columns